# Showing all possible routes in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm building google maps mobile application using google maps API v2 and I managed to draw a route between two locations. The problem is that I want to show all the possible routes to the direction location not just one. Can you help me, please? 
I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Is this a new take on the [Traveling Salesman Problem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: Directions API can return up to 3 different routes when you use `alternatives=true` parameter: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters

Comment: Thanks @xomena for guidance